# JSON API Call with Custom Taxonomy Terms

Tags: php, json

I have two separate functions that work fine independently. The first is a JSON api call, my first shot at a api call. Second is a foreach loop retrieving a taxonomy term->name from a post-id.

My question is how do I incorporate these two functions. For example I don't want to show all the prices returned from the api but just the ones that are in the the "investment" taxonomy for the current page. Also for the taxonomy I have a custom taxonomy field called cmc_ticker that is the same id as used in the api, may make it easier. Just having trouble wrapping my head around this one. Any thoughts/advice appreciated..

JSON API Call - Returns ~ top 100

```
<?php
$json_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$links = json_decode($json, TRUE);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($links['data'] as $key=>$val){
    ?>
    <li>
           <?php echo $val['name'] ?>
           <?php echo $val['id'] ?>
           <?php echo $val['symbol'] ?>
           <?php echo $val['rank'] ?>

    </li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Function returning of taxonomy term->name

```
<?php

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'investment' ) ;


if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { ?>

<div class="card mb-4">
<div class="card-header text-white bg-warning">Investments</div>
<ul class="list-group">

    <?php
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>

        <li class="list-group-item border-0">
        <?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?>


        </li><?php
    }

    ?>
</ul>
</div><?php
}

?>
```